# How different are "Kill Doctor Lucky" and "Save Doctor Lucky"?

Tags: kill-doctor-lucky, save-doctor-lucky

I've played "Kill Doctor Lucky" and highly enjoy it.  A great, light, game that non-gamers quickly pick up and play easily.  In this game, players move from room to room in a mansion, trying to get Dr. Lucky out of sight of other players so they can kill him.

I'm considering purchasing "Save Doctor Lucky."  It looks like this game reverses the intent.  Players move from room to room in the Titanic, hoping to be in sight of another player as they save Dr. Lucky (so they can be known as a hero).

Obviously, the mechanics sound similar.  I'm wondering what the overall feel of the game is.  Does it offer new and interesting strategies?  Will my family, who are veteran assassins from the first game, find it interesting?  Or is it "just a skin" on the old game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save Dr Lucky is similar in some ways, but does play differently. In order to increase the chance of success as the game progresses, the board shrinks one deck at time as the Titanic sinks, which means forces the players closer together. This can be annoying when you are holding on to room cards for a lower deck that has just sunk.

It is definitely worth owning if you enjoy Kill Dr Lucky. I will say that it doesn't play very well if you don't have at least four players.